# If $a$ and $b$ are odd perfect squares, then $a + b$ is not a perfect square.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

> Prove: If $a$ and $b$ are odd perfect squares, then $a + b$ is not a perfect square.

**Proof by Contradiction:**

If $a$ and $b$ are odd perfect squares then $a = (2k+1)^2$ and $b = (2r + 1)^2$.

Assume $a + b$ is a perfect square.

\begin{align}a + b &= (2k+1)^2 + (2r + 1)^2\\
&= 4(k^2 + r^2) + 4(k + r) + 2\\
&= 4(k + r)^2 + 4(k + r) -2kr +  2\\
&= z^2 + 2z -2kr +  2 \hspace{0.5cm} \text{where } z = 2(k+r)\\
&= (z+1)^2  -2kr +  1\\
&= (z+1)^2  - q \hspace{0.5cm} \text{where } q = 2kr + 1\end{align}

Hence, $a+b$ is in inexpressible as a perfect square when $a, b$ are odd.

Is this a valid proof? I'm not sure how to approach it any other way.

Comment: use properties of pythagorean triple in wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

In you second line you have shown that a+b mod 4 = 2. Is this possible if a+b is a perfect square ?

Answer (score 2):

You could stop at $4(k^2 + r^2) + 4(k + r) + 2$ and note that this is divisible by $2$, but not $4$. Therefore it cannot be a square.

Comment: If I continued past that line would what I have be fine? I'm not sure I see the significance of being divisible by 2, but not 4, sorry!

Comment: @Philip The square of any even number is divisible by $4$. The square of an odd number is not divisible by $2$. Also note that it is sometimes useful to know (and you may be able to prove) that the square of an odd number is always one more than a multiple of $8$.

Comment: Oh right, I see. So I could have considered $a = 2k +1$ and $b = 2r +1$ and reasoned through to arrive at $a + b = 2(k+r+1)$? Then, since this is indivisible by 4, it cannot be the square of an even number, which would be as we'd expect since the sum of two odd numbers is even?